# Listview Grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've come across this tutorial

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

However I'm struggling to write the LinqDataSource query in C Sharp.

```
var o = (from c in x group c by c.Date into cc select new { Group = cc.Key, ItemCount = cc.Count() });
```

The above is fine but how do I add the "It as Items" into the above query as per the LinqDataSource in the link I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group` clause creates `IGrouping`s.  An `IGrouping` is basically an `IEnumerable` with a key, so accessing its items is just like accessing an `IEnumerable`'s items.  This statement uses `ToList()`, but you could also use `AsEnumerable()` or `ToArray()`:

```
var o = from c in x 
        group c by c.Date into cc 
        select new { Group = cc.Key, Items = cc.ToList(), ItemCount = cc.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

I added code to your query

```
  var o = 
    (from c in x 
     group c by c.Date into cc 
     select new { Group = cc.Key, ItemCount = cc.Count() });

    foreach (var grp in o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nCategoryID Key = {0}:", grp.Key);
        foreach (var item in grp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", item.Items);//Replace with your property
        }
    }
```

You can use yield in order to enumere